# About actions of ${\rm Aut}(G)$, conjugacy classes and inner automorphisms of said group

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, automorphism-group

Let $G$ be a group, show that $\text{Aut}(G)$ acts on the set $\mathscr C$ of the conjugacy classes of $G$ with the action given by $\varphi(\mathscr C_x)=\mathscr C_{\varphi(x)}$ with $\varphi\in\text{Aut}(G)$ and $\mathscr C_x$ the class of $x$.

Also we have to show that $\mathscr F(G)=\{\varphi\in\text{Aut}(G)\mid \varphi(\mathscr C_x)=\mathscr C_x\}$ is normal in $\text{Aut}(G)$ and that $\mathscr F(G)$ contains the inner automorphisms given by conjugation.

__

This was an assignment for my group theory course. I've done this course, rep theory and rings and modules.
*The* problem I'm having is that I don't know how to tackle this exercise with the things we've been taught on the group theory course, because we skimmed over the automorphisms (and their actions) part, and focused more on cyclic and Sylow groups and that kind of stuff.

I've tried seeing that the difference of two elements in the same coclass is sent into that class itself and to expand the product of the action, but can't go further than that

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Rather than just tells us what you have been assigned to do, we prefer if you provide context for your question: what your level is, and more particularly, what you have attempted to do and why you are unable to complete the argument. That will ensure that any replies you receive are at the appropriate level and addressing the relevant issues.

Comment: Please put the information in the question, not the comments. And don't forget to include what you have managed to do and where you are stuck. Otherwise, the question may be closed until you provide that information (and then it would take affirmative action by users to re-open it; better to head it off at the pass).

Comment: I've added the info here to op, and expanded a bit. 
Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ on $G$ is simply $\varphi\cdot g = \varphi(g)$.

The conjugacy class of $x\in G$ is $\mathcal{C}_x=\{gxg^{-1}\mid g\in G\}$. You want to verify that applying $\varphi$ to each element of $\mathcal{C}_x$ will result precisely in $\mathcal{C}_{\varphi(x)}$.  You will need to use that $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism, and that it is invertible.

For the second part, start by showing that the set in question is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$: the identity morphism lies in the set, and if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ both lie in the subset, then so does $\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$. Just check directly what happens with the inner automorphisms.

Finally, show that if $\varphi$ lies in the subset, and $\sigma$ is *any* automorphism, then $\sigma^{-1}\varphi\sigma$ is in the subgroup; that means that you need to show that if $\mathcal{C}_x = \mathcal{C}_{\varphi(x)}$, then $\mathcal{C}_{\sigma(x)} = \mathcal{C}_{\varphi(\sigma(x))}$, using the first part.

Comment: For the last part is enough showing that $\sigma(\varphi(\sigma^{-1}(\mathscr C_x)))=\mathscr C_x$ right? And that's because $\varphi (\mathscr C)=C$.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: @GonzaloMartínez: Showing that is exactly the same, yes.

Comment: If the (supposed) action is *defined* by $\varphi\cdot \mathscr{C}_x:= \mathscr{C}_{\varphi(x)}$, then: 

 a) $\iota \cdot \mathscr{C}_x = \mathscr{C}_{\iota(x)} =  \mathscr{C}_x$;
 b) $\sigma\cdot(\tau\cdot\mathscr{C}_x) = \sigma\cdot\mathscr{C}_{\tau(x)} = \mathscr{C}_{\sigma(\tau(x))} = \mathscr{C}_{(\sigma\tau)(x)} = (\sigma\tau)\cdot \mathscr{C}_x$,

so it is an action, indeed. But if so, where am I using the fact that group elements are automorphisms (rather than bijections on a set $X$) and $\mathscr{C}_x$ are conjugacy classes (rather than elements of a set indexed by $X$)?

Comment: @user750041: No, the action is defined by taking a subset $X$ of $G$ and sending it to $\{\varphi(x)\mid x\in X\}$. The goal is to **prove** that this action will send $\mathcal{C}_x$ to $\mathcal{C}_{\varphi(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

As the action is on a set of *classes* (necessarily dealt with by means of representatives), we have first to prove that the map is well defined, namely that $x'\in \mathscr C_x \Rightarrow \varphi\cdot\mathscr C_{x'}=\varphi\cdot\mathscr C_{x}$. This in indeed the case, because:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\mathscr C_{\varphi(x')} &= \{g\varphi(x')g^{-1}, g\in G\} \\
&= \{g\varphi(g'xg'^{-1})g^{-1}, g\in G\} \\
&= \{g\varphi(g')\varphi(x)\varphi(g')^{-1}g^{-1}, g\in G\} \\
&= \{(g\varphi(g'))\varphi(x)(g\varphi(g'))^{-1}, g\in G\} \\
&= \{g''\varphi(x)g''^{-1}, g''\in G\} \\
&= \mathscr C_{\varphi(x)} \\
\end{alignat}

where the last but one equality follows from $g\mapsto g\varphi(g')$ being *onto* $G$, for every $g'\in G$. Next, $\varphi\cdot\mathscr C_x\in \mathscr C$ by definition. Furthermore, $Id_G\cdot \mathscr C_x=\mathscr C_{Id_G(x)}=\mathscr C_x$. Finally, $(\varphi\psi)\cdot\mathscr C_x=\mathscr C_{(\varphi\psi)(x)}=\mathscr C_{\varphi(\psi(x))}=\varphi\cdot(\psi\cdot\mathscr C_x)$. So, this is indeed a group action and $\mathscr F(G)=\operatorname{Stab}(\mathscr C_x)$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Then:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\psi\operatorname{Stab}(\mathscr C_x)\psi^{-1} &= \{\psi\varphi\psi^{-1}\mid \varphi\cdot\mathscr C_x=\mathscr C_x\} \\
&= \{\rho\mid (\psi^{-1}\rho\psi)\cdot\mathscr C_x=\mathscr C_x\} \\
&= \{\rho\mid \rho\cdot (\psi\cdot\mathscr C_x)=\psi\cdot\mathscr C_x\} \\
&= \operatorname{Stab}(\psi\cdot\mathscr C_x)
\end{alignat}

so $\mathscr F(G)$ is not normal in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$. Rather, here we get that the stabilizers of the points of one same orbit are all conjugate to each other. Last, if $\varphi\in\operatorname{Inn}(G)$, then $\exists g\in G$ such that $\varphi\cdot\mathscr C_x=\mathscr C_{\varphi(x)}=\mathscr C_{gxg^{-1}}=\mathscr C_x$, whence $\varphi\in\mathscr F(G)$. Therefore,  $\operatorname{Inn}(G)\le\mathscr F(G)$. (Note that this holds for every conjugacy class considered in $\mathscr F(G)$, and hence $\operatorname{Inn}(G)\le\operatorname{ker}\phi$, where $\phi$ is the homomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\to S_\mathscr C$ equivalent to your action.)

---

**Comment**. If the action is defined by $\varphi\cdot\mathscr C_x:=\mathscr C_{\varphi(x)}$, then the proof of the good definition focuses on the invariance w.r.t. representative's choice, being the membership of $\varphi\cdot\mathscr C_x$ to $\mathscr C$ trivial (by definition); this is the above approach. Conversely, if the action is defined by $\varphi\cdot\mathscr C_x:=\varphi(\mathscr C_x)$, then the proof of the good definition focuses on the membership of $\varphi\cdot\mathscr C_x$ to $\mathscr C$, being the invariance w.r.t. to representative's choice trivial (as $x'\in\mathscr C_x\Rightarrow \mathscr  C_{x'}=\mathscr C_x$). The effort in both approach is the same, and equal to proving that $\varphi(\mathscr C_x)=\mathscr C_{\varphi(x)}$.